# she not go to live with her father (in past)

Tags: past-tense

Can we use *not go* in past? For example, this sentence:

> She not go to live with her father.

I am not sure if I can use this sentence like this:

> She did not **went** to live with her father.

or:

> She did not **go** to live with her father.

Answer (score 1):

The negative conjugation of English past-tense verbs can seem tricky, but fortunately it's pretty regular.  Similar to the negation of the simple present tense, use the *infinitive* or *base* form of the verb and add "did not".

> She went ⟶ She **did not go**.
>
> They saw ⟶ They **did not see**.
>
> I ate ⟶ I **did not eat**.

And so on.  "I did not went" is never grammatical.

Your sentence would be:

> She **did not go** to live with her father.

Alternately you can use the contraction *didn't*:

> She **didn't** go to live with her father.

[More on conjugating the simple past](https://www.thoughtco.com/esl-simple-past-tips-and-quiz-4176634)